# Is it possible to speed up barh plots when plotting thousands of bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I need to plot a pair of charts with thousands of horizontal bars each. The only reasonable output format I got was using Matplotlib's hbar. I prepared a simplified code that generates some random figures and plot the same chart I use (see code after the picture below; you might need to change the size of the figure so you can see the whole picture on your screen).

On my laptop (a Lenovo Yoga 920; 8th Gen Intel Core i7-8550U) it takes almost a minute to plot the charts. Is there something I can do to make these charts faster to plot?

UPDATE AND SOLUTION: After a suggestion from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I run a quick experiment using LineCollection. I included this study on my own answer below - hopefully, it will help some coders to understand faster how LineCollection works. After the study, the final code I wrote. It takes now a little more than one second to plot a very similar chart vs. my original one!

**THE CHART I NEED TO PLOT**
[image]

**THE ORIGINAL CODE**

```
def chart_size_and_font (width, length, font):

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] #set chart size; as multiples charts will be ploted, the overall chart needs to be big
    fig_size[0] = width
    fig_size[1] = length
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font}) #set font size for all charts (title, axis etc)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# generating some random figures
sim_days = [datetime.today() - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(2000)]
positive_1 = np.random.normal(100, 20, (2000,4))
negative_1 = np.random.normal(-100, 20, (2000,4))
positive_2 = np.random.normal(100, 20, (2000,4))
negative_2 = np.random.normal(-100, 20, (2000,4))

run_start = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("-----------------------------------------")
print("Run start time:", time_now)
print("-----------------------------------------")

#color map (repeating sequence in case plotting more contributor than the original four most positive/negative)
color_map_blue = ['mediumblue','royalblue','dodgerblue','skyblue', 'mediumblue','royalblue','dodgerblue','skyblue']
color_map_red = ['firebrick','red','salmon','mistyrose', 'firebrick','red','salmon','mistyrose']

chart_size_and_font (39, 30, 20) # set charts width, lenght and fonts

chart_f = plt.figure()
st = chart_f.suptitle("FIGURE TITLE", fontsize=25)
st.set_y(0.93) #move position of suptitle; zero puts it at bottom of chart

days = positive_1.shape[0] #same as "len" of array
count = positive_1.shape[1] #number of columns

chart_p = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
pos_left = np.zeros(days)
neg_left = np.zeros(days)
for n in range(count):
    chart_p = plt.barh(y=sim_days, width=positive_1[:,n], left=pos_left, align='center', height=2, color = color_map_blue[n])
    pos_left += positive_1[:,n]
    chart_p = plt.barh(y=sim_days, width=negative_1[:,n], left=neg_left, align='center', height=2, color = color_map_red[n])
    neg_left += negative_1[:,n]
plt.title("SUBPLOT 1 TITLE", fontsize=20)
ax = plt.gca() # get current axis ('x' and 'y') to be formated
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ax.get_xticks().tolist()]) # format x-axis labels
plt.grid()

chart_p = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
pos_left = np.zeros(days)
neg_left = np.zeros(days)
for n in range(count):
    chart_p = plt.barh(y=sim_days, width=positive_2[:,n], left=pos_left, align='center', height=2, color = color_map_blue[n])
    pos_left += positive_2[:,n]
    chart_p = plt.barh(y=sim_days, width=negative_2[:,n], left=neg_left, align='center', height=2, color = color_map_red[n])
    neg_left += negative_2[:,n]
plt.title("SUBPLOT 2 TITLE", fontsize=20)
ax = plt.gca() # get current axis ('x' and 'y') to be formated
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ax.get_xticks().tolist()]) # format x-axis labels
plt.grid()

plt.show()

run_end = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("\n-----------------------------------------")
print("Run end time: ", time_now)
print("Time to run:", timedelta(seconds=run_end-run_start))
print("-----------------------------------------")
```

Comment: It seems the bars might be better represented as lines in this case where you have as many bars as pixels or even more. The fastest way to plot many lines would be a `LineCollection`. This will definitely be much faster than plotting bars, I would estimate a couple of seconds max.

Comment: Thank you  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for your suggestion. However, after running a simple test with LineCollection (see above my edited question) I have the impression that this approach will make the chart plotting process even longer.

Comment: Yeah, there are too many lines. What I meant was rather something along the lines of `segs = np.zeros((line_number, 2, 2), float);
segs[:,1,1] = ys;
segs[:,0,0] = x;
segs[:,1,0] = x`.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the clarification - my understanding of how LineCollections work was wrong. I was plotting 2,000 lines with 1,999 segments each! I just added an answer with a "study" on how to use LineCollection (the example from Matlibplot's documentation was less straightforward). I will eventually add the final code with the new chart - it should take a few seconds to plot (as on my study, it plots 2,000 lines, with 4 segments in 1.3 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @ImportanceOfBeingErnest guidance, I prepared a study on how to use LineCollection to plot a big group of lines. Just after the study, the final solution: a code that plots a very similar chart vs. my original one, in one second!

**THE STUDY**

Below is a code that plots a series of lines. The figure below shows 20 lines: easy to follow the color and line-width changes. It takes a nill time to plot. The second figure shows 2000 lines: it took 1.3 seconds to plot.

[image: 20 lines plot]

[image: 2,000 lines plot]

**THE STUDY CODE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

line_number = 2000

day = array(range(0,line_number))
change = np.random.rand(line_number)
all_zeros = np.zeros(line_number)

run_start = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("-----------------------------------------")
print("Run start time:", time_now)
print("-----------------------------------------")

color_map = ['red', 'blue','green','orange','pink']

# We need to set the plot limits.
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(0, change.max()*3)
ax.set_ylim(0, day.max()*3)

segs = np.zeros((line_number, 4, 2), float) # the 1st argument refers to how many lines will be plotted; the 2nd argument to coordinates per lines (which will plot one fewer line-segments as you need two coordinates to form the first line-segment); the 3rd argument refers to the X/Y axes

segs[:,0,1] = day           # Y-axis
segs[:,0,0] = all_zeros     # X-axis / setting using the variable "all zeros" not necessary (as segs was already all zeros) - included for clarity

segs[:,1,1] = day*2         # this is the 2nd data-point, forming the first line segment
segs[:,1,0] = change

segs[:,2,1] = day*1.5       # this is the 3rd data-point, forming the second line segment
segs[:,2,0] = change*2

segs[:,3,1] = day*2.5       # this is the 4th data-point, forming the 3rd line segment
segs[:,3,0] = change*3

line_segments = LineCollection(segs, linewidths=(4, 3, 2, 1, 0.5), colors=color_map) # the color_map will be used by "complete segment"
ax.add_collection(line_segments)

ax.set_title('Plot test: ' + str(line_number) + ' lines with LineCollection')
plt.show()

run_end = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("\n-----------------------------------------")
print("Run end time: ", time_now)
print("Time to run:", timedelta(seconds=run_end-run_start))
print("-----------------------------------------")
```

**THE FINAL CODE**

```
# LineCollection chart

def chart_size_and_font(width, length, font):

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] #set chart size; as multiples charts will be ploted, the overall chart needs to be big
    fig_size[0] = width
    fig_size[1] = length
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': font}) #set font size for all charts (title, axis etc)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dates = 2000

# generating some random figures
sim_days = array(range(0,dates))
positive_1 = np.random.normal(100, 20, (dates,4))
negative_1 = np.random.normal(-100, 20, (dates,4))
positive_2 = np.random.normal(100, 20, (dates,4))
negative_2 = np.random.normal(-100, 20, (dates,4))

run_start = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("-----------------------------------------")
print("Run start time:", time_now)
print("-----------------------------------------")

days = positive_1.shape[0]      # same as "len" of array
count = positive_1.shape[1]     # number of columns

#color map (repeating sequence in case plotting more contributor than the original four most positive/negative)
color_map_blue = ['mediumblue','royalblue','dodgerblue','skyblue', 'mediumblue','royalblue','dodgerblue','skyblue']
color_map_red = ['firebrick','red','salmon','mistyrose', 'firebrick','red','salmon','mistyrose']

chart_size_and_font (40, 40, 20) # set charts width, lenght and fonts
chart_f = plt.figure()
st = chart_f.suptitle("FIGURE TITLE", fontsize=25)
st.set_y(0.93) #move position of suptitle; zero puts it at bottom of chart

chart_p = plt.subplot(1,2,1)

pos_sum = np.sum(positive_1, axis=1) # add array rows
neg_sum = np.sum(negative_1, axis=1)
chart_p.set_xlim(neg_sum.min(), pos_sum.max()) #set plot axes limits
chart_p.set_ylim(0, sim_days.max())

coord_1 = np.zeros(dates)
coord_2 = np.zeros(dates)
for n in range(count): # plot positive values on first chart
    coord_2 += positive_1[:,n]
    segs = np.zeros((dates, 2, 2), float)
    segs[:,0,0] = coord_1       # X-axis coordinates - start of line
    segs[:,0,1] = sim_days      # Y-axis coordinates - start of line
    segs[:,1,0] = coord_2       # X-axis corrdinates - end of line
    segs[:,1,1] = sim_days      # Y-axis coordinates - end of line
    line_segments = LineCollection(segs, linewidths=2, colors=color_map_blue[n])
    chart_p.add_collection(line_segments)
    coord_1 += positive_1[:,n]

coord_1 = np.zeros(dates)
coord_2 = np.zeros(dates)
for n in range(count): # plot negative values on first chart
    coord_2 += negative_1[:,n]
    segs = np.zeros((dates, 2, 2), float)
    segs[:,0,0] = coord_1
    segs[:,0,1] = sim_days
    segs[:,1,0] = coord_2
    segs[:,1,1] = sim_days
    line_segments = LineCollection(segs, linewidths=2, colors=color_map_red[n])
    chart_p.add_collection(line_segments)
    coord_1 += negative_1[:,n]

chart_p.set_title('Plot test 1: ' + str(dates) + ' lines with LineCollection')
plt.grid()


chart_p = plt.subplot(1,2,2)

pos_sum = np.sum(positive_2, axis=1) # add array rows
neg_sum = np.sum(negative_2, axis=1)
chart_p.set_xlim(neg_sum.min(), pos_sum.max()) #set plot axes limits
chart_p.set_ylim(0, sim_days.max())

coord_1 = np.zeros(dates)
coord_2 = np.zeros(dates)
for n in range(count): # plot positive values on first chart
    coord_2 += positive_2[:,n]
    segs = np.zeros((dates, 2, 2), float)
    segs[:,0,0] = coord_1       # X-axis coordinates - start of line
    segs[:,0,1] = sim_days      # Y-axis coordinates - start of line
    segs[:,1,0] = coord_2       # X-axis corrdinates - end of line
    segs[:,1,1] = sim_days      # Y-axis coordinates - end of line
    line_segments = LineCollection(segs, linewidths=2, colors=color_map_blue[n])
    chart_p.add_collection(line_segments)
    coord_1 += positive_2[:,n]

coord_1 = np.zeros(dates)
coord_2 = np.zeros(dates)
for n in range(count): # plot negative values on first chart
    coord_2 += negative_2[:,n]
    segs = np.zeros((dates, 2, 2), float)
    segs[:,0,0] = coord_1
    segs[:,0,1] = sim_days
    segs[:,1,0] = coord_2
    segs[:,1,1] = sim_days
    line_segments = LineCollection(segs, linewidths=2, colors=color_map_red[n])
    chart_p.add_collection(line_segments)
    coord_1 += negative_2[:,n]

chart_p.set_title('Plot test 2: ' + str(dates) + ' lines with LineCollection')
plt.grid()

plt.show()


run_end = timer()
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print("\n-----------------------------------------")
print("Run end time: ", time_now)
print("Time to run:", timedelta(seconds=run_end-run_start))
print("-----------------------------------------")
```

**THE FINAL CHART**

I still need to format the Y-axis labels, as I couldn't use "dates" for the Y-axis values. The result, however, is very similar to my original chart (but 50x faster to plot):

[image: Final chart]